# error when trying to edit .bash_profile - receiving error with conda initialize

Tags: bash, vim

I am locked out of my `.bash_profile` and wanted to edit it (With regards to the introductory module to Git on Udacity). Unfortunately conda appears to not allow me to edit this as when I used the command in bash

```
vim ~/.bash_profile
```

it copies out this message

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/rohanbansal/Desktop/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/rohanbansal/Desktop/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/rohanbansal/Desktop/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/rohanbansal/Desktop/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"~/.bash_profile" 16L, 535C
```

Comment: That's not an error, that's what the Vim text editor looks like. You can type `<ESC>:q!` to quit -- that's the escape key, a colon to bring up the command prompt, and the `q!` command to quit without saving. Go look up Vim tutorials to learn how to use it. It's not intuitive and none of us could hope to explain how to use it here in a single comment or answer.

Comment: It just so happens that your `~/.bash_profile` has the text "Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init'" and such. It's not an error; that's what's in the file. It's a warning saying, "Maybe don't touch these lines. They were created by an external tool and you should probably use that tool to make updates and not edit them by hand."

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error! It's the content of your `~/.bash_profile.`

You can view it using `cat ~/.bash_profile`

Editing with vim isn't intuitive. You can learn with `vimtutor` command or from the internet.
Take a look here https://opensource.com/article/19/3/getting-started-vim